# Python: What is the "size" parameter in Gensim Word2vec model class

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I have been struggling to understand the use of `size` parameter in the `gensim.models.Word2Vec`

From the Gensim documentation, `size` is the dimensionality of the vector. Now, as far as my knowledge goes, word2vec creates a vector of the probability of closeness with the other words in the sentence for each word. So, suppose if my `vocab` size is 30 then how does it create a vector with the dimension greater than 30? Can anyone please brief me on the optimal value of `Word2Vec` size?

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec#Dimensionality
If there usually is no way of know what an optimal value will be

Comment: Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga but I am still not able to get the math behind it. How can 34 words have embeddings for 100 hundred words i.e. if size = 100? Is there any paper, blog or tutorial explaining this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`size` is, as you note, the dimensionality of the vector.

Word2Vec needs large, varied text examples to create its 'dense' embedding vectors per word. (It's the competition between many contrasting examples during training which allows the word-vectors to move to positions that have interesting distances and spatial-relationships with each other.)

If you only have a vocabulary of 30 words, word2vec is unlikely an appropriate technology. And if trying to apply it, you'd want to use a vector size much lower than your vocabulary size – ideally *much* lower. For example, texts containing many examples of each of tens-of-thousands of words might justify 100-dimensional word-vectors.

Using a higher dimensionality than vocabulary size would more-or-less guarantee 'overfitting'. The training could tend toward an idiosyncratic vector for each word – essentially like a 'one-hot' encoding – that would perform better than any other encoding, because there's no cross-word interference forced by representing a larger number of words in a smaller number of dimensions.

That'd mean a model that does about as well as possible on the Word2Vec internal nearby-word prediction task – but then awful on other downstream tasks, because there's been no generalizable relative-relations knowledge captured. (The cross-word interference is what the algorithm *needs*, over many training cycles, to incrementally settle into an arrangement where similar words *must* be similar in learned weights, and contrasting words different.)

Comment: This is such a great explanation. This makes so much sense. Thanks a lot, @gojomo

Comment: If you end up here and wondering how to get the embedding vector size from the model, it is `model.vector_size`.

Answer (score 0):

It's equal to vector_size.
To make it easy, it's a uniform size of dimension of the output vectors for each word that you trained with word2vec.